# How can I specify a regex in a zgrep/zcat command?

Tags: regex, linux, zcat, zgrep

I want to find in a list of words, every words with a least 3 times the same letter in it. To achieve that I did  `.*(\w).*\1.*\1.*\1.*` and you can test it here http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html but I don't know how to put it in my `zgrep` command.

How can I insert this regex in a `zgrep` command ?

Comment: You might need to replace `\w` with `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Comment: Hey you already helped me earlier ! I tried but I have `invalid back reference`

Comment: Yes, you also need to create a capturing group. Try  `zgrep '\([[:alnum:]_]\).*\1.*\1.*\1' a.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- You do not need to match start and end of a line with `.*` since partial matches are allowed
- `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores in NFA regex patterns, in POSIX, it is safer to use `[[:alnum:]_]`
- To form a capturing group in a POSIX BRE pattern use escaped parentheses, `\(...\)`.

Thus, use

```
zgrep '\([[:alnum:]_]\).*\1.*\1.*\1' a.gz
```

Or, contract it a bit since it looks a bit redundant with three consecutive `.*\1` subpatterns:

```
zgrep '\([[:alnum:]_]\)\(.*\1\)\{3\}' a.gz
```

Comment: Is it a medium to contact you ? I have more questions about regex and zgrep but I don't want to spam creating a lot of posts

Comment: @J.erome Please join the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200941/room-for-wiktor-stribizew-and-j-erome).

Comment: So, to match 3 or more times, use `\{3,\}` instead of `\{3\}`.